# Unknown exact format of COBOL-85 source files

Tags: cobol, file-format, cobol85

I need to parse some legacy COBOL-85 files that exhibit some lines that are shorter than the expected 80 chars. An example is below.

```
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.                                         00000000<-- line ends here
   01  VAR1                          PIC S9.                        00000000<-- line ends here
  * COMMENT 1                                                       00000000<-- line ends here
       COPY SQLCA.                             00000000<-- line ends here
  * COMMENT 1                                                       00000000<-- line ends here
       COPY COPY1.                             00000000<-- line ends here
       COPY COPY2.                             00000000<-- line ends here
  * COMMENT 1                                                       00000000<-- line ends here
  * COMMENT 2                                                       00000000<-- line ends here
   05  FILLER                        PIC X(10).                             <-- line ends here
   05  VAR2.                                                        00000000<-- line ends here
       10  VAR3                      PIC  X(8).                     00000000<-- line ends here
```

Is this a special format/dialect?
Some files have IBM-4381 as SOURCE-COMPUTER, some others have IBM-3090.

By the way, I tried to treat specially the case of the 59 chars line, but other source files in the same program are different, with no comment area or spaces at the end, having length <= 80 chars. So in these files a line can have 59 characters, but is not parsable as the special line, expecting to have the comment area at the end.

Comment: No! It is not a _special format/dialect_. Every occurrence of `00000000` in `Area B` (prior to column 73) would be a syntax error.

Comment: note: some compilers allow to adjust the right margin of area b (normally only use to extend area b, I don't know if some compilers allow to make it smaller). If this "working" COBOL code the I'm sure it (at least originally) used a tab to position (the tab-positioning is compiler specific, most use 8 (or 4 or adjustable) character positions, some use positions like 7,12,72, ...

Comment: IBM's OS/VS COBOL compiler had some odd quirks.  It's _possible_ that the `00000000` was tolerated on compiler-directing statements like `COPY`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. @cschneid, so I will try restricting special case to COPY statements and similar ones and see what happens